# How to mock the HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have a function that looks for a query parameter and returns a boolean:

```
  public static Boolean getBooleanFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        Boolean keyValue = false;
        if(request.getParameter(key) != null) {
            String value = request.getParameter(key);
            if(keyValue == null) {
                keyValue = false;
            }
            else {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    keyValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return keyValue;
    }
```

I have both junit and easymock in my pom.xml, how do I go about mocking the HttpServletRequest ?

Comment: The below answer this question as written well, but I would normally advocate for refactoring the code so that most of the non-trivial logic is in at a more appropriate level of abstraction. If that's possible, then mocking HttpServletRequest becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HttpServletRequest is much like any other interface, so you can mock it by following the [EasyMock Readme](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking)

Here is an example of how to unit test your getBooleanFromRequest method

```
// static import allows for more concise code (createMock etc.)
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;

// other imports omitted

public class MyServletMock
{
   @Test
   public void test1()
   {
      // Step 1 - create the mock object
      HttpServletRequest req = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);

      // Step 2 - record the expected behavior

      // to test true, expect to be called with "param1" and if so return true
      // Note that the method under test calls getParameter twice (really
      // necessary?) so we must relax the restriction and program the mock
      // to allow this call either once or twice
      expect(req.getParameter("param1")).andReturn("true").times(1, 2);

      // program the mock to return false for param2
      expect(req.getParameter("param2")).andReturn("false").times(1, 2);

      // switch the mock to replay state
      replay(req);

      // now run the test.  The method will call getParameter twice
      Boolean bool1 = getBooleanFromRequest(req, "param1");
      assertTrue(bool1);
      Boolean bool2 = getBooleanFromRequest(req, "param2");
      assertFalse(bool2);

      // call one more time to watch test fail, just to liven things up
      // call was not programmed in the record phase so test blows up
      getBooleanFromRequest(req, "bogus");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Use some mocking framework e.g. [**Mockito**](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or [**JMock**](http://www.jmock.org/) which comes with mocking capacity of such objects.

In Mockito, you can do mocking as:

```
 HttpServletRequest  mockedRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

For details on Mockito, see: [How do I drink it?](http://site.mockito.org/#how) on the Mockito site.

In JMock, you can do mocking as :

```
 Mockery context = new Mockery();
 HttpServletRequest  mockedRequest = context.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

For details on jMock, please refer: [jMock - Getting Started](http://www.jmock.org/getting-started.html)

Comment: Because they use generics with type inference like any good modern library should.

Comment: You are passing `.class` as an argument to mock methods.

Comment: @Hiro2k - That's what I would have expected, but I don't see any generics in the examples on the website... ?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(java.lang.Class)
See the generics in the method signature?

Comment: @Hiro2k - I think I'm just confusing Java and C#. In C#, generic method calls include the generic in `<>` brackets (`mock<HttpServletRequest>(...)`) while it looks like that's not the case in Java.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old thread ... but the question is still relevant.

Another good choice is MockServiceRequest and MockServiceResponse in the Spring framework:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about easymock, but the book ['Unit Testing in Java: How Tests Drive the Code' by Johannes Link](http://books.google.com/books/about/Unit_Testing_in_Java.html?id=enIzSnJkKAYC) contained explanations of how to test Servlets using a library he'd build of dummy objects.

The companion site for the book is now gone (change in publishing company of something...) but [the companion site from the original german publication is still up](http://www.dpunkt.de/utmj/). From it, [you can download the definitions of all the dummy objects](http://www.dpunkt.de/utmj/utmj-servlet.zip).

Comment: The publisher site links are giving 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mockrunner: http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/

It has a lot of easy to use Java EE mocks, including HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.