# how to mock ServletActionContext.getRequest() using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, jmockit

I try to make unit test on Function `queryInfo` of Class `queryAction`:

```
public class queryAction{
    public String queryInfo(){
    // do something...
    // this line throw Exception
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String areaInfo = request.getParameter("paramJson");
    // do something...
    }
}
```

when the unit test is running, Reported the following error：

> queryAction(com.huawei.provision.queryActionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.047
>   sec  <<< ERROR!
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>          at org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext.getRequest(ServletActionContext.java:112)

And I looked up some questions and answers, such as [one way using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517374/how-to-mock-servletactioncontext-getrequest-using-mockito-we-are-using-struts2) and [another way using easymock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945907/how-to-mock-the-httpservletrequest) But I still don't know how to solve this problem by `JMockit`.

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you've tried. Where's your attempt at a unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the luxury of returning `areaInfo` in `queryInfo()` for this test.

In your case, you should use `@Mocked` for both objects and return the `HttpServletRequest` mock in the call from `ServletActionContext.getRequest()` in an expectation.

```
package com.platypus;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Tested;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;


@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class ServletActionContextTest
{

    @Tested
    private QueryAction queryAction;

    @Mocked
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
    @Mocked
    private ServletActionContext servletActionContext;

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws Exception
    {
        new Expectations(){{
            ServletActionContext.getRequest(); result = httpServletRequest;
            httpServletRequest.getParameter("paramJson"); result = "foo";
        }};

        String queryInfo = queryAction.queryInfo();

        assertEquals("foo", queryInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your reason for stating that "faking should be used" for static methods? You can absolutely still use `@Mocked` in these cases.

Comment: For me is kind of a rule of thumb, maybe I should rethink it.

Comment: Good call @dcsohl No need for faking ;)

Comment: Right - I'm not necessarily discouraging the use of faking; I just wanted to point out it wasn't *necessary*. (Though I admit that faking is not my preference; I like the Mocking syntax and use cases a lot better.)